# C# Windows 10 modern system tray menu

Tags: c#, contextmenu, system-tray

How can I create a  menu (in the system tray) in C# similar to the one in the picture.

[image]

I know there is the option of using the normal context menu but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Menu or icon?....

Comment: Menu I have the Icon and the basic context menu. I didn´t know that these menus are called "toast notifications".

Answer (score -1):

Since Windows 8, Microsoft introduced Toast Notifications. This is what you are searching for. Toast Notifications allow more customisation over ballon notification.

MSDN has some nice and straight forward information about Toast Notifications, I would recommend reading more in here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802768(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Will this allow me to make a menu that opens when I click the icon in the system tray or just a notification?